# html, body {height: 100%} is always displaying scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and in custom css saying

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

when added, it always displays vertical scrollbar. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you made sure that html and body have margin, padding, and border set to 0?

Comment: had to fix it using $(windows).height(), nothing else seems to have been working https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1671

Answer (score -2):

add to the css:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: That may mask the problem, but may lead to content being hidden.